# / UI Layout Initialization Error The center-pane element does not exist. The center-pane is a required element

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to stackoverflow and also this my very first question to this forum so if i am doing something wrong when i am posting here please let me know.

my question related to primefaces i tried with lot of solution but nothing work for me.

i am using...

- jsf 2.2.4
- primefaces 5.2
- tomcat 8

below code is the my template.xhtml
it's located on /templates/template.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:view contentType="text/html" id="fview">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Page template with PrimeFaces</title>
<ui:debug />
<f:metadata>
    <ui:insert name="metadata" />
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
    <p:layout fullPage="true" resizeTitle="resize"
        style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="68" id="north">
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" resizable="false" size="225">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerLayout">
            <h:form id="mainForm">
                <p:messages autoUpdate="true" id="msgs" showDetail="true"
                    showSummary="true" />
                <ui:insert name="content" />
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="0"
            style="width:0px; display:none;" id="east">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" resizable="true" id="south">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>

</h:head>
```

And below code is my home.xhtml
it's located on pages/home.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
template="../templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="metadata">
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    Hello world! Welcome to a page derived from a template 
</ui:define>
```

when i run my application request successfully go to the controller and return. But browser come up with alert

**> / UI Layout Initialization Error
The center-pane element does not exist.
The center-pane is a required element.**

If any one know the proper answer for my question please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No offence, but I'd strart by searching SO or google with this exception.

Comment: NO pal.. i already tried with that but that's not worked for me. I already added that part to web.xml but that's not worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your components and tags structure is all wrong. Here is how it should look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:view encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html">

    <ui:insert name="metadata" />

    <h:head>
        <title>Page template with PrimeFaces</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:debug />
        <p:layout fullPage="true" resizeTitle="resize" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="68" id="north">
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" resizable="false" size="225">
                <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerLayout">
                <h:form id="mainForm">
                    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" id="msgs" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />
                    <ui:insert name="content" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="0" style="width:0px; display:none;" id="east">
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" resizable="true" id="south">
                <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>
    </h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

- The main mistake: layout and content belong in body, not head.
- Title and meta tags must be in head.
- Template can't use f:metadata. The client view can. See [f:metadata doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/metadata.html).
- Define content type and encoding in f:view.
- There is no `id` attribute in f:view.

By the way I don't recommend using ui:debug. It evaluates all the properties it can see, and sometimes provokes undesirable side-effects.

Comment: It's working now!!! thank you sooo much... unfortunately i can't rate your answer because of i am new to here. but your answer is worked for me. thank you again you save my time. and also you gave nice explanation for  what i did wrong. thanks for all of that. I learned lot of things from you. thanks

Comment: compliments... I just can't put myself to creating such answers for people that do not post what they tried and what did not work...

Comment: @randikaisuru, to accept the answer click the checkmark to the left of the answer, it's right below the voting arrows.

Comment: Oh!! sorry i didn't know about that. now all things are OK i think.